# How to bump the C++ standard from the CMake command line?

Tags: c++, cmake, c++17, c++20

Currently I have a project that needs C++17, therefore in the `CMakeLists.txt` I have this line pretty early on:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
```

From the command line (`cmake`) once in a while I want to test that the project also compiles with C++20. (to avoid surprises).

**How can I choose to compile with C++20 from command line?**

If I do `cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=20` then it is later overwritten by the configuration instead of 17 being interpreted as just a minimum requirement.

I could check if the variable is predefined to avoid overwritting but I was looking for a more declative way to specify this.

(I am using cmake around 3.18.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is to remove that set command and use target properties instead:

```
# set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
target_compile_features(myexecutable PUBLIC cxx_std_17)
```

Then, setting `-DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=20` on the terminal should work again.

Comment: *"All variables that starts with CMAKE_xxxxx is usually meant for usage in terminal,"* There are a large number of variables with the `CMAKE_` prefix where this is not true. The recommendation is a good one though...

Comment: The original `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)` is global (for good or for bad). Can `target_compile_features(myexecutable PUBLIC cxx_std_17)` be made global somehow?

Comment: @alfC the most "global" would be you making an interface only target like `common-properties` target that has all common properties and you link each targets to it. Still non global though, otherwise you stay with the compiler's default.

Comment: What do you mean by `common-properties`?

Comment: @alfC `add_library(common-properties INTERFACE)` then `target_compile_feature(common-properties INTERFACE cxx_std_17)` then `target_link_libraries(myexecutable PUBLIC common-properties)`

Comment: Is `common-properties` a keyword or a variable made up name?

Comment: @alfC The name of the target created with `add_library(common-properties INTERFACE)`. You can call it `potato` if you wish, `common-properties` is a made up name.

Answer (score 5):

Make `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` a cache variable. This allows you to easily specify a default that can be overwritten via the command line. Note that you need to make sure no "normal" `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` variable is available, since this value would take precedence over the cache variable.

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17 CACHE STRING "the C++ standard to use for this project")

add_library(...)
```

Using `cmake -D CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=20 binary_dir` should allow you to update the standard now, `cmake -U CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD binary_dir` should revert back to the default.

---

Alternatively you could create a custom cache variable. This would make a reuse easier, since it would allow you to overwrite the property, even if someone else sets `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` before using `add_subdirectory` to add your project.

```
set(MYPROJECT_CXX_STANDARD 17 CACHE STRING "the C++ standard to use for myproject")

# overwrite possibly preexisting value for this directory and subdirectories
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD ${MYPROJECT_CXX_STANDARD})

add_library(...)
```