# CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD vs target_compile_features?

Tags: c++, cmake, c++20

I'm itching to upgrade our project to C++20. My `CMakeLists.txt` files generally say

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
```

but I get the sense that's not the Right Way to do it. What is the Right Way? Is it this?:

```
target_compile_features(Foo PUBLIC cxx_std_20)
```

where `Foo` is the name of my target (and same for every target?) If I do that, do I the remove all the `set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD*)` lines everywhere?

Along the same lines, If I have

```
target_compile_features(Foo PUBLIC cxx_std_20)
target_compile_features(Bar PUBLIC cxx_std_17)
target_link_libraries(Bar PUBLIC Foo)
```

does that mean that when it goes to build `Bar` it will note that it needs to include headers from `Foo` and `Foo` needs `cxx_std_20` and `cxx_std_20` includes `cxx_std_17` and so `Bar` will be built with C++20?

Comment: Possible duplicate [How to bump the C++ standard from the CMake command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70566491/how-to-bump-the-c-standard-from-the-cmake-command-line)

Comment: I should have linked to that. I agree it's getting at the same thing. I'm not sure if it's really a dup or not. I see that one as "I have `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)` how do I make it so I can change that on the cmd line?" vs "What's the Right Way to do CXX versions?". Feel free to close as dup if you like.

Comment: I am not voting for closing the question as a dup, because the question body is very different, but the answer would be the same: `cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=20` will not work if `set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)` is in CMakeLists.txt.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The newer alternative is definitely

```
target_compile_features(Foo PUBLIC cxx_std_20)
```

And with this you can and should remove the old `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD*)`.

However the new version has an issue if you also want to disable compiler extensions with `set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)`. Its not possible with the new syntax as far as I know and combining both of them does not work either.

And the second part of your question: Yes, cmake will recognize the dependencies and put the compiler in `c++-20` mode whenever necessary.

Comment: For completeness, to disable compiler extensions per target you can do `set_target_properties(Foo PROPERTIES CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)`.

Comment: Can you say anything about the degree to which setting `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` will fight with `target_compile_features(... cxx_std_*)`?

Comment: No, I don't know the internals of cmake here.. but a good a new question.
What I can say is that the command `set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)` has no effect if you specified `target_compile_features(... cxx_std_XX)` but it has an effect if you specify `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD XX)` or `set_target_properties(... PROPERTIES CXX_STANDARD XX)`. So there must be some difference in how these statements work.

Comment: With `target_compile_features` you specify a minimum standard required. With `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` you specify which standard is used, respecting the minimum standard required:
    ```set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
    target_compile_features(main PRIVATE cxx_std_17)```
results in `-std=c++17`
    ```set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
    target_compile_features(main PRIVATE cxx_std_17)```
results in `-std=c++20`

Comment: @undefined So, in a nutshell, will it use always the newer?

Comment: @ViniciusAlmada In this example yes. But with `target_compile_features` you can specify different c++ standards for different targets and if your use `PUBLIC` instead of `PRIVATE` the standard will also propagate if you link against the target (Very useful if you export a target).