# What is the difference between the various methods of selecting the C standard in cmake

Tags: c, cmake

There are multiple ways of setting a C standard in CMake.
I know of at least 4:

```
project(Test C)
add_executable(test test.c)

target_compile_features(test PRIVATE c_std_90) # (1)
add_definitions(-std=c90)  # (2)
set (CMAKE_C_STANDARD 90)  # (3)

# I assume 4a and 4b are identical 
set_target_properties(test PROPERTIES C_STANDARD 90) # (4a)
set_property(TARGET test PROPERTY C_STANDARD 90)  # (4b)
set_property(TARGET test PROPERTY C_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_compile_options(-pedantic)
```

What is the difference between these 4 options? For this piece of C code only some of them will result in a warning. I would have assumed they all do the same in the background.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("Hello world! %llu", 1ull);
    return 0;
}
```

The above code is not C90 compliant, why do only (2) and (4) result in the warning:

```
/home/hkoep/work/tools/test.c:4:32: warning: use of C99 long long integer constant [-Wlong-long]
    4 |     printf("Hello world! %llu", 1ull);
```

(1) and (3) don't produce the same warning.

Comment: Both (4) and (5) sets the same property, but use different commands. Which command to select is up to you. "which one is the recommended one to enforce C90?" - Stack Overflow is not a good place for ask what is **recommended**. We (community) are not developers of a particular language or technology, so our "recommendations" are never official one. Answers for the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851247/how-do-i-activate-c-11-in-cmake describe possible ways for set C/C++ standard in CMake. Some answers even contain "recommended" word. It is up to you to choose.

Comment: The line `add_definitions(-std=c90)` will break down if used with a compiler that does not understand that option. Avoid it for portability.

Comment: Hi @Tsyvarev I removed the word recommended and asked a more tangible question instead. The post you linked doesn't answer the question why some produce a warning and some don't.

Comment: "why do only some of them result in a warning?" - Is it a puzzle where we should **guess** which exact variant result in a warning and which one is not? Instead, show the exact, **single** variant which doesn't work for you. So you will got answer(s) about what you are doing wrong.

Comment: I wasn't supposed to be a quiz :). I updated the question to indicate which of the 4 options produce a warning and which ones don't.

Comment: Setting `CMAKE_C_STANDARD` variable doesn't affect on **already created** targets: this variable just provides default value of the C_STANDARD property for newly created target. Concerning `c_std_90` compile feature, it doesn't disable compiler extensions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70667513/cmake-cxx-standard-vs-target-compile-features. Have you noticed that your 2 attempts are failed because of **different reasons**? Moreover, one of those attempts is already described in the existing Q/A. This is why in the previous comment I asked you about the **single** variant.

Comment: Thanks, it didn't notice that, but makes sense now.
From the other thread I also learned that `target_compile_features(test PRIVATE c_std_90)` sets the minimum standard to be used. Does that mean `target_compile_features()` is the wrong function to use if I want to restrict my code to c90 and throw a warning if any >= c99 is used?